# Can I skip the declaration of a method/function (output) variable if I just want it to be printed?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

class myClass {

public:
  void compute(int& x, int& y) {
    y = 2*x;
  }

};


int main()
{
    int input = 5;
    int output;
    
    myClass myobj;
    myobj.compute(input, output);
    std::cout << "Result is: " << output << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I was wondering if there is some C++ notation to just print `output` without having to declare it first. Like if the function was defined as `int compute(int& x)` we could write `myobj.compute(input)` directly in the `cout` line. Because I use a library, there is no room for me to redefine it like this though.

So, does something like

```
std::cout << "Result is: " << output <- myobj.compute(input, output) << std::endl;
```

exist (where output does not have to be defined)?

Comment: `int compute(int& x) {
    return 2*x;
  }` ... `std::cout << "Result is: " << myobj.compute(input) << std::endl;` may be??

Comment: Why not have `compute` return a value, and then you can do `std::cout << "Result is: " << myobj.compute(input) << std::endl`.

Comment: _" I use a library, there is no room for me to redefine it"_ - seems to be a showstopper. What's the name of the library, class (in that library) and member function (in that class) that you are using?

Comment: There is nothing that would make your code shorter and/or easier to read. It is really on the library for not using return values instead of output parameters. In modern C++ it isn't likely that output parameters have a benefit over return values.

Comment: http://docs.ros.org/en/jade/api/grid_map_core/html/classgrid__map_1_1GridMap.html#ad70705d82a28b4c5da92efdbff52fd7b

Library is this ^. I omitted it to make example easier.

Comment: You can still add wrapper to replace output parameter by return value.

Comment: @Tetix Ok, and what class and member function?

Comment: @TedLyngmo The one the link heads to, getPosition() with 2 arguments and bool return value.

Comment: Ok, so I take it that _"`true` if successful, `false` if index not within range of buffer"_ is not important in your program?

Comment: This is more general question, so assume that any return value (like this true/false) can be thrown out (that's why I used a void return type in my example).

Comment: @Tetix Ok, then I think creating a wrapper/helper class is your best bet. If you need it for many classes/member functions, not only classes with a `compute` (or `getPosition`) member function, it'll be a lot more work.

Comment: I am actually looking if something exists so that it can be used in many more places and with other/various number and type of function input/output parameters. Something in-line basically.

Comment: It's certainly possible to create a more generic helper class than the one I put in the answer, but it's a lot of work. It will most probably be inlined if used as I showed.

Comment: The short answer is "no".   The type of all variables must be specified and, if a function accepts an `int` by non-`const` reference, the caller is required to define an `int` in order to pass it.   You can create a wrapper to take care of that (e.g. `int myCompute(int input) {MyClass obj; int output; obj.compute(input, output); return output;}`) but that doesn't remove the need to define relevant variables - it simply hides the deed in another function.

Answer (score 1):

No, there's nothing that will provide that functionality automatically. You could however create a helper class that calls `compute`:

```cpp
template<class T>
struct computer {
    int operator()(int& input) const {
        int output;
        obj.compute(input, output);
        return output;
    }
    T& obj;
};
// deduction guide:
template<class T>
computer(T) -> computer<T>;
```

which would then be used like so:

```cpp
int main() {
    myClass myobj;
    int input = 5;

    std::cout << "Result is: " << computer{myobj}(input) << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Actually reworked by Ted Lyngmo.

You can probably make a function adapter. Not sure anymore about the newest C++, but somehow it should not need that overhead in the first answer.

Below the function `f` applies any in-out procedure to an input and returns the output.

```
#include <iostream>

template<class T>
int f(T& inst, void(T::*myocomp)(int&, int&), int inputval) {
    int output;
    (inst.*myocomp)(inputval, output);
    return output;
}

int main() {
    myClass myobj;
    int input = 5;

    std::cout << f(myobj, &myClass::compute, input) << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: No, that won't work unfortunately. [Here's your code fixed](https://godbolt.org/z/vT3WqbdsY) if you'd like to make it work.

Comment: I can see how this approach can be useful. I am actually looking if something exists so that it can be used in many more places and with other/various number and type of function input/output parameters without having to redefine wrapper functions each time. Actually, this library I am using has many similar functions with various arguments that I am using. Just wanted to make initial post concise/easier.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I was afraid of the need of a full specification. Java which is my main bread & butter has some interface magic corresponding to C++ templates. BTW I Was the first upvoter of you

Comment: @JoopEggen Oh, thanks :-) Yeah, C++ is a bit picky when it comes to these things, but your main idea is nice so you could put the code (that I just brushed up a bit) in your answer. It's a little more generic than the solution I put in my answer so you'd get my vote :-)